# Is it possible to save pointer to function member from a derived in another class used by a base class

Tags: c++, reference, pointer-to-member

Basically I have a class let's say `Parameter` that has a get and set variable.

I also have a base class let's say `Vehicle`  that has a method `registerParameter(...)`  that takes a pointer to function member as getter and a pointer to function member as setter. This method is then supposed to write those two pointers into an object of the parameter class and throws this object into a vector.

And last but not least we have a derived class let's say `Car` and we call `registerParameter(...)` with the string `"color"` as parameter name and a getter and setter from this derived class.

Example in code:

Parameter file

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include "base.h"

class Parameter
{
    std::string (Base::*get)();
void (Base::*set)(std::string);
};

#endif
```

Base file

```
#ifndef PARAMETER_H
#define PARAMETER_H
#include <vector>
#include "parameter.h"

class Base
{
  public:
std::vector<Parameter> list;
void registerNew(std::string (Base::*get)(), void (Base::*set)(std::string))
    {
        Parameters parameter;
        parameter.get = get;
        parameter.set = set;
        list.push_back(parameter);
}
};

#endif
```

Derived file

```
class Derived
{
  public:
    Derived derived() 
    {
        registerNew(&getColor, &setColor);
    }

    std::string getColor()
    {
        return this->color;
    }

    std::string setColor(std::string newColor)
    {
        this->color = newColor;
    }
  private:
    std::string color;
};
```

I've been thinking about this for days now and I really need the solution until friday evening.

Comment: So your problem is that getColor and setColor are not acceptable in registerNew?
You could always loosen the rules a bit and instead of getting a strict function pointer just have the function receive `void*` but then when you want to use it you will have to cast it correctly

Comment: Despite the missing question mark on the question title it says what I need.

Comment: @inneedofhelp: That would be very bad idea. It's much better to take a `std::function<void(std::string)>` and `std::bind` the `Derived*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what are trying:

The types `std::string (Base::*)()` and `std::string (Derived::*)()` are very different. `std::string (Derived::*)()` cannot be auto converted to `std::string (Base::*)()`.

Take the following scenario.

```
struct Base
{
    int foo() { return 10; }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    int bar() { return 20; }
};

int main()
{
    Base base;

    int (Base::*bf)() = &Base::foo;
    (base.*bf)(); // Should be able to call Base:foo(). No problem.

    bf = &Derived::bar; // This is a compiler error. However, if this were allowed....
    (base.*bf)(); // Call Derived::bar()?? That will be a problem. base is not an
                  // instance of Derived.
}
```

**Update**

You can do something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base;

// Create a base class Functor that provides the interface to be used by
// Base.
struct Functor
{
   virtual ~Functor() {}
   virtual std::string get(Base& base) = 0;
   virtual void set(Base& base, std::string) = 0;
};

// Create a class template that implements the Functor interface.
template <typename Derived> struct FunctorTemplate : public Functor
{
   // typedefs for get and set functions to be used by this class.
   typedef std::string (Derived::*GetFunction)();
   typedef void (Derived::*SetFunction)(std::string);

   // The constructor that uses the get and set functions of the derived
   // class to do itw work.
   FunctorTemplate(GetFunction get, SetFunction set) : get_(get), set_(set) {}

   virtual ~FunctorTemplate() {}

   // Implement the get() function.
   virtual std::string get(Base& base)
   {
      return (reinterpret_cast<Derived&>(base).*get_)();
   }

   // Implement the set() function.
   virtual void set(Base& base, std::string s)
   {
      (reinterpret_cast<Derived&>(base).*set_)(s);
   }

   GetFunction get_;
   SetFunction set_;
};

class Base
{
   public:
      std::vector<Functor*> functorList;

      void registerFunctor(Functor* functor)
      {
         functorList.push_back(functor);
      }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived() 
    {
       // Register a FunctorTemplate.
       registerFunctor(new FunctorTemplate<Derived>(&Derived::getColor, 
                                                    &Derived::setColor));
    }

    std::string getColor()
    {
        return this->color;
    }

    void setColor(std::string newColor)
    {
        this->color = newColor;
    }
  private:
    std::string color;
};
```

Comment: Is there an alternative? Or a solution to go around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your base class should know the derived class. That sounds complex but the problem has been solved already:

```
template<typename DERIVED> class Base
{
public:
   class Parameter {
     std::string (DERIVED::*get)();
     void (DERIVED::*set)();
   };
private:
   std::list<Parameter> list;
   // ...
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> // !!!
{
   registerNew(&Derived::getColor, &Derived::setColor);
};
```

This solution is known as the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP).

Comment: @PascalNeubert: It's not necessary, just convenient (saves repeating the template parameter).